# Use RunningValue in CRM Dashboard Chart?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dashboard, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there a way i can use runningvalue()expression in a CRM Dashboard Chart?, like in SSRS reports ,Or add to to the existing aggregate methods ,Avg,Count:All,Count:Non-empty, Max ,Min ,Sum

[image]

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to do it.

Comment: is this what you're talking about? https://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/2015/03/23/add-key-figures-to-dashboards-in-ms-dynamics-crm/

Comment: @Andrii,Thanks, What!!! :( .

Comment: @Shane_Yo, What I'm trying to display is the Cumulative Sales per month in a chart on Dashboard.

Comment: You can add your suggestion on Connect portal. That could help to bring this feature to the next release - [https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions)

Comment: You should be able to show stuff like sales per month - no worries.

Comment: Thanks @Andrii Butenko , i will add that suggestion, is there another way i could get the cumulative sales ?

Comment: @Shane_Yo, Yep i can  show sales per month , can i add equations to the charts?

Comment: Your  equations are limited to Data you query within your fetch, or the legend aggregates.

Comment: @Shane_Yo, So its only those in the image above i can use?

Comment: You could be more creative with your fetchxml if you export your chart and work with it outside of the crm interface.

Comment: @Shane_Yo, okay, I have exported it to xml, but not sure where to start as very new to fetch xml.

Comment: See if the link I posted above will help, it does take some time to get used to working with fetchxml -  there are tools on the net also